# Optionals in Swift, why this simple code doesn't print optional?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, swift-playground

```
var shoppingList = ["item1": "bread", "item2": "milk" ]

if let oldItem = shoppingList.updateValue("honey", forKey: "item2") {
    println("old value was \(oldItem)")
}

// This prints out "old value was milk"
```

However, if I do this

```
var shoppingList = ["item1": "bread", "item2": "milk" ]

let oldItem = shoppingList.updateValue("honey", forKey: "item2")
println("old value was \(oldItem)")
// This would print out "old value was Optional("milk")

if oldItem != nil {
   println("old value was \(oldItem)")
}

// And this prints out the same "old value was Optional("milk")
```

Why is that happening here and not in the if statement in the first example?

NOTE: I am testing this in playground, Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Comment: Because `if let` unwraps optionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var shoppingList = ["item1": "bread", "item2": "milk" ]

if let oldItem = shoppingList.updateValue("honey", forKey: "item2") {
    println("old value was \(oldItem)")
}

// This prints out "old value was milk"
```

Because this code (the `if let` statment) unwraps the value for key "`item2`", and stores the unwraped value in `oldItem`.

If you'd just print it like this:

```
let oldItem = shoppingList.updateValue("honey", forKey: "item2")
println("old value was \(oldItem)")
```

It would print `Optional("old value was milk")`

But if  there wouldn't be any value for the key `item2`, then the program would crash.

Comment: Why `if let` statment unwraps the value? is it something I learn by experience? or is there a reason behind it?
And btw, when I tried to do this `shoppingList.updateValue("honey", forKey: "item3")` which is adding new key value, thus returns nil to oldItem, it didn't crash, it printed out `old value was nil`

Comment: Its the Swift syntax, its the rule of the if let statment. Its explained in the Swift docomentation.

Comment: But shouldn't the example I mentioned above crash the program? where I receive a `nil` from `updateValue` and then try to print out the variable holding the `nil`?

Comment: No, because thats the if let for. If let someVar = otherVar{ ... } this unwraps the otherVar, and stores it to someVar, but if otherVar is nil, then the  if let skips this block of code.

Comment: Without the If let, here is what I mean
`let oldItem = shoppingList.updateValue("honey", forKey: "item3")`

 `println("old value was \(oldItem)")`
This prints "old value was nil" since there is no key called item3.
This doesn't crash.

Comment: Yes, but if you would do this: println("old value was \(oldItem!)"), with the "!" to force unwrap the value, it would crash with "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 1):

The method **updateValue** on dictionary returns the value that has been replaced. So when you do

```
if let oldItem = shoppingList.updateValue("honey", forKey: "item2")
```

The replaced value which is milk is returned to the oldItem.

```
println("old value was \(oldItem)")
```

oldItem returns the old value it posses.

Note: When you do updateValue on dictionary, the new key/value pair is updated if the key is presented. If the key is not presented then the new key/value pair is added to the dictionary. And the updateValue returns the old updated value if the key is exists and returns nil if not.